# TableView does not disappear when setHidden function is called

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I,

In my handleLongPress function (cf: gesture recognizer), I try to make a TableView appear, and at the end, when gesture is remove, disappear. for that I use the gesture recognizer state property along with setHidden function for tableView. Unfortunately, the tableView, after appearing doesnt disappear. I dont understand why. If you have an idea, I would be thankful.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(gestureRecognizer.view.center.x - 10, gestureRecognizer.view.center.y - 10, 100, 100)];

    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
    tableView.layer.frame = CGRectInset(tableView.layer.frame, 20, 20);


    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    [self addSubview:tableView];
    }

    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [tableView setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are recreating the table view everytime and either adding it to the screen or not, you need to capture your tableview in a property or an ivar, then go from there, im assuming you only want one table view, the following will fix the issue

In your interface have a tableView property

```
@interface ..
{

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

synthesize this in your implementation...

```
    -(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    {
       if(tableView==nil)
      {
        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(gestureRecognizer.view.center.x - 10, gestureRecognizer.view.center.y - 10, 100, 100)] autorelease];
      [self addSubview:self.tableView];
     }

        self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
        self.tableView.layer.frame = CGRectInset(tableView.layer.frame, 20, 20);


        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
           [self.tableView setHidden:false];
        }

        if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
        }
   }
```

For more information on properties check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) out
hope it helps..
Daniel

Comment: Surprising, the tableview appears and disappears one time but not after. If checked and the "if" blocks are regularly called. Its like the setHidden function could'nt be called two times from YES to NO. And it is the same thing with the opaque function.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    [tableView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

since you are adding a tableview, you should be removing it. else, add the tableview outisde your longPressGestureRecognizer method, and hide/unhide as required

Comment: try it with the setHidden: YES and remove from Superview lines in there. If the tableview is still visible, then the tableView is being added or made visible somewhere else